# Facing issues when writing multiple rows to a csv file in python 3.6

Tags: python, csv

My requirement is to read all the files in the directory and get the length of the file, and word count of each file and store it as a row in a CSV file.

Following is my Python code.
      #Iterating through the list directory

```
 for filename in os.listdir(passedArgument1):
  #Opening each file in the directory
   with open(passedArgument1+filename,"r",encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
    actualWordCount = 0
  # Getting the file Size
    fileSize=os.path.getsize(passedArgument1+filename)
    for line in f:
  # Getting the word count
      actualWordCount+=writeToExcelFile(line)
  # Writing to a file 
      with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
       spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|',   quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
       spamwriter.writerow([actualWordCount,fileSize])
```

When I am writing to the CSV file, it writes only one record that is the last file. I have checked writerows method but not sure how it works.Any help is appreciated on achieving my requirement in Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

```
csvfile = open('output.csv', 'w')
# do your loop here and write/append to csvfile
csvfile.close()
```

Comment: Explicit `close()` is not best practice in Python for the past 7-10 years.  OP is already using `with` which is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

You are re-opening the output file for every single line of output.  Just open it once.

Comment: I tried to open once , by putting the open method on the top ,but it gave me the following error . ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: @Sumanth: Well then don't close the file.  Perhaps your indentation was wrong.  You need to write INSIDE the `with open`.

Comment: Working on that , will update once i check your suggestion